# How to modify the List view column?

Tags: c#, listview, decimal, datarow

I have list view  the data will be displayed in list view from data table 
like this i have done but i have problem at datarow 6

```
           dt = classes.xxxxx.GetData(sql, mf);

  if (dt != null)
  {
    ListViewItem newitem = null;
    lstviewcashmembers.Items.Clear();
    lstviewcashmembers.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
      newitem = lstviewcashmembers.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[3].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[4].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[5].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[6].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[7].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[8].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[9].ToString());
      newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[10].ToString());
      newitem = null;
    }

    lstviewcashmembers.EndUpdate();
  }
```

my problem is like I got original value coming from database is 25.00000 at dr[6]

I mean  in this line newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[6].ToString());

But I have to show only two decimal places like this 25.00

Would any one help this?

Comment: valuable Question +1 for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 string r = "1000.123456";
 var t = string.Format("{0:#.##}",decimal.Parse(r)); //1000.12
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
dr[6].ToString("N2")
```

Update:

```
((double)dr[6]).ToString("N2")
```

The N2 must be done on a numeric type, so the cast is necessary on the DataRow object.

Comment: got an error No Over Load method for To string Takes one argument newitem.SubItems.Add(dr[6].ToString("N2"));

Comment: @user682417: Hmmm, maybe dr[6] must be cast to a double first... updating answer

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Down give the Correct Answer.  Try dr[6].ToString("0.00") also

And try to read [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) For More Information About Format.

Happy Coding.